# Running a program with/without sudo?

Tags: server, permissions, qbittorrent

Im using qbittorrent-nox on an Ubuntu server 14.04 install.  Im trying to get the program to run unrar on torrents but it doesn't work.  The command:

```
sudo unrar x -r %f/%n/*.rar /mnt/
```

works when typed in the command prompt and I can enter a sudo password, but obviously I cant do that within the program.

I guess basically, how do I either give qbittorrent-nox root rights or make unrar not require them?

Answer (score 4):

You would need to either:

- Change the write permission of the target directory (in this case `/mnt`, which is a system folder owned by `root` by default) so it is accessible by your own user, or
- Change the target directory to somewhere where your user has write access.

Either of those ways will prevent you from having to use `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by editing the /etc/sudoers file. The command to edit the file is 'sudo visudo'. I'll post the commands to add in an edit.